# Secure CRUD endpoints

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to secure with Roles the CRUD endpoints that are automatically created by:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user"),
```

It is very easy to do with defining antmatchers and `hasAuthority` for everything, but I cant give antmatchers for each repository endpoints as the application grows, it isn't sustainable to always go back and edit the security config. 
So to be clear, I am looking for something like `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation and in this similar annotation to define maybe which roles connect to which methods in the repository, like:

```java
@SomeAnnotation(Post.Method.hasAuthority(PRODUCT-UPDATE),Delete.Method.hasAuthority(PRODUCT-DELETE),
```

current repo looks like this:

```java
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String>
{

    User findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);
    User findByLastName(@Param("lastName") String lastName);
    User findByUserName(@Param("userName") String userName);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're looking for `@PreAuthorize`. So your repo could look something like:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User,String>
{

    @GetMapping("/byFirstName")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_CLIENT') and #oauth2.hasScope('viewUser')")
    User findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);

    @PostMapping("/save")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    Long save(@Param("user") @RequestBody User user);    
}
```

See [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security) for more details.

Comment: I would really only need the basic method "endpoints". So in this case only the "/user" endpoint but different roles for PostMapping, DeleteMapping etc. Same as if i said .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/user/**").hasAuthority("DELETE-USER")

Comment: Not sure that I follow. You want to be able to specify, per resource, based on request type? e.g. all `GET` access to `/user` resource must have a given role, all `POST` access a different given role, etc.?  Or you want to say that any `GET`, not matter the resource must have a specific role, different role for every `POST` in the app, etc?

Comment: Yeh so on the /user for different CRUD methods,post,delete,put etc a different role like:USER-DELETE,USER-POST

Comment: So my teacher told me now with what i should best achieve this: Spring Aspect Oriented Programming(AOP), and with that i should check if the user has access and roles to post delete etc.

Comment: I mean, you can roll your own AOP stuff - [here's an example of that](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-aop-security), but know that Spring Security uses AOP internally. If the point of the exercise is to secure an application, I (and any security expert) would strongly advise you against writing your own security stuff. If the point is to play with AOP, then by all means - but then please rephrase your question. Also, what exactly about the proposed solution does not meet your requirements? I am still trying to understand that.

Comment: Well it does solve the problem actually, so i will accept it, thanks:) Although my teacher wouldnt accept it, because he wants to be able to make a repository, and without writing any other code he wants it to automatically be secured by roles and authorities(So that nothing can be fogotten, cuz its automatically done i guess). I am at a company learning, so i am guessing that this would be the right way to do it here with AOP.            (neither did i know that it has to be with aop, thats why the question was about how i thought it could be)

Comment: Ahh I understand now. You might want to ask another question, and be a bit more specific about what you're looking for - i.e. that things are automatically pre-authorized based on the request type.